# Blaze DS unable to use my-streaming-amf - "Destination 'chat' not accessible over channel 'my-amf'

Tags: blazeds, amf

Can anyone point me out whats wrong with the configuration I have to execute a simple sample application to use the streaming-amf.

I get the following error when i tried to submit a text and get the same using streaming-amf.

My messaging-config.mxml has the following lines.

```
<destination id="chat">
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-polling-amf"/>
        <channel ref="my-streaming-amf"/>
    </channels>   
</destination>
```

I've defined the channels detail in the service-config.xml.

When I tried the application, instead of using "my-streaming-amf" the app was constantly pointing to "my-amf" and throwing the following error

"Destination 'chat' not accessible over channel 'my-amf'.

any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SWF you are loading probably has the channel set compiled into it.  Maybe it's not recompiling with your new channel information or the SWF is cached in your browser.

Comment: Awesome. I re-ran my build script to compile the SWF file and it worked like charm. Thanks James.